use VS be used, sell VS be sold - passive voice?

1.a Most of the machines aren't ready to use yet.


1.b Most of the machines aren't ready to be used yet.

Based on my research I believe both are grammatically correct, but I still have trouble understanding to use in the first sentence.
Machines can't use anything, so it's clear that both sentences are clearly used in a passive voice. Why is the first sentence correct? Shouldn't the usage of a passive voice take the form of be+p.p, making the first sentence incorrect?
A similar problem I have with another sentence :

2.a It is said that Korean used cars sell well in Russia.
2.b It is said that Korean used cars are sold well in Russia.

Another example with the same verb 'sell' :

3.a This cheese should be sold by May 31st.
3.b This cheese should sell by May 31st.

Are both sentences correct in these examples too, and why? What are other verbs beside use and sell that follow this pattern when using a passive voice?

Ready to eat (food) and ready to wear (garments) are common  expressions - easier to say than 'ready to be eaten' and not likely to be misunderstood. For sell, see this question

Does this answer your question? "To be" in front of adjective? Also 'ready to measure' or 'ready to be measured'?, and Your order is "ready to be delivered" or "ready to be shipped"?, and Ready to be taken, and Is ready to watch or Is ready to be watched?, and many, many more.
